# IWebHostBuilder.GetSetting() doesnt have appsettings.json data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working on refactoring an ASP.Net Core v1 application to v2.  The gist of the current effort is moving the database seeding logic to Program.Main() as indicated in the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/#move-database-initialization-code)...

> In 2.0 projects, move the `SeedData.Initialize` call to the Main
>   method of Program.cs:

The problem I am encountering is that I need to get a config flag out the `appsettings.json` file.  This **appears** to be loaded by default when [WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/) is called as per the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L152), but my code isn't able to retrieve a simple flag from my `appsettings.json`.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

    string env = builder.GetSetting("environment");
    var envMsg = "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT/Environment variable ";
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(env))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("environment", envMsg + "missing!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine(envMsg + "found!");

    string doSeed = builder.GetSetting("SeedDb");
    var seedMsg = "SeedDb in appsettings.json ";
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(doSeed))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("SeedDb", seedMsg + "missing!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine(seedMsg + "found!");

    return builder.Build();
}
```

The `environment` variable is set (as [expected](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L173)), but the values from the json file do not appear to be.  No exception on env check, but there is on the seed flag.

Repo [here](https://github.com/bigteejay/SO_CreateDefaultBuilderNoAppSettings) to verify if needed.  What am I missing? I've seen mention of prefixing the setting to search for with "AppSettings", etc... but I don't see that indicated in the source (and can't verify what it **should be**, if anything.)

Comment: GetSetting applies to the builder config, the app's config hasn't been loaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the results from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46574602/3246805), I have it figured out...

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = BuildWebHost(args);

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var config = services.GetService<IConfiguration>(); // the key/fix!
        var s = config.GetValue<string>("SeedDb");
        var doSeed = bool.Parse(s); // works!
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

Or just `var doSeed = config.GetValue<bool>("SeedDb");`!